# How do i add elements to a jList from another class?

Tags: java, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am using **netbeans** 6.9.1.  I have a jframe, and the jframe has a jList and the DefaultListModel name is lm. I would like to add elements to this jList using another class, but i can't figure out how, and can't find anything on it online...I guess i have to find a way to get the DefaultListmodel into my class also...?

- **I know how to add elements within the jframe class**, using addElement() however from a different class i am stumped.

thanks -jason

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you mean by "different class"? Code snippets might help...

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here... your question needs a little more detail as Nivas pointed out.

But it sounds like *crosses fingers* you need to expose your list model as a property and manipulate that from the external class.

Comment: okay, so how do i do that?  i have this on my jframe class  public DefaultListModel lm = new DefaultListModel();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ListModel is created at an earlier stage (like when the JFrame class is initialized), you should have a public method that takes in the item you want to add and adds it to the list model.